# Activating Acrobat from powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, adobe-acrobat

I wanted to activate Acrobat Reader from Powershell. How would I go about doing that?
I have a key and Admin Permissions.

Comment: So far as I know, you do not have to activate Reader. The user is (heavily) encouraged to sign in.

Comment: I assume you talk about Acrobat Pro vs Acrobat Reader. Adobe has made it like this: you install adobe acrobat pro, it replaces adobe acrobat reader, then you login with an account that has a license, and that's it. The issue is that if you do this on a computer or server with multiple accounts, you replace adobe reader for ALL users, and only your user can then use adobe acrobat pro, and the rest can't view pdf's anymore using adobe.

Comment: @John do you know if there is a way for me to automatically sign-in a machine?

Comment: I have not seen a way to do that, no.

Comment: You can start by editing your question to clarify if your talking about Acrobat or Reader, likewise, which version you have installed